# Firebase `is not a function` Error with firebase 5.11.1 and greater

Tags: javascript, firebase, create-react-app

With these in my package.json

```
"firebase": "^5.11.1",
"react-scripts": "3.0.1",
```

and then running `react-scripts start`

with this `index.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/functions';

const config = {
  apiKey: "XXXXX-XXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXX.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXX"
};


firebase.initializeApp(config);

const functions = firebase.functions();
```

I get this error.

```
TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.functions is not a function
Module../src/index.js
src/index.js:16
  13 | 
  14 | firebase.initializeApp(config);
  15 | 
> 16 | const functions = firebase.functions();
  17 |
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this bug there seemed to have been something not right in the package-lock.json file. when I deleted it and npm installed it started to work.

The version of firebase that had the issue started at 5.5.9. at 5.5.8 it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import firebase itself too

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

Also, after you do that `initializeApp()` call make sure to initialize functions

```
firebase.functions()
```

**UPDATE**: In regards to your updated question's code, the code should work, please try deleting your node modules and re-running yarn or npm install (based on which package manager you use)

Comment: thanks for being so fast. I miss copy/pasted and I do have that line.